# Front and backend public files not found

Tags: files, 9

I'm trying to display some image in my front and my backend, a simple image, not a media, but I'm always receiving a 404.

For example, I'm trying to display the icon from my paragraph, to i'm extracting the URL, but when I call it, I have a 404. Where does this error come from ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, for some reason, the permission of **web/site/default** was this (change to **755**)

> drwxrwx--- 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 juil.  2 15:45 default